# Retain latest record by differentiate "actual NULL in data" vs "NULL due to field not being present" in record using trino

Tags: sql, presto, trino, apache-iceberg

I have an iceberg table like below and trying to run a query using trino to provide the expected output.

**Sample Data**

```
trino:datalakepartncr_trino> select src.ID, src.OUTSTANDING1, src.OUTSTANDING2, src.OUTSTANDINGP, src.LASTACTION, src.LASTACTIONDATE, pos,changed_cols from table_event where src.ID in (4998,4952,4959) order by pos;
  ID  | OUTSTANDING1 | OUTSTANDING2 | OUTSTANDINGP | LASTACTION |   LASTACTIONDATE    |       pos       |                    changed_cols
------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 4952 |          0.0 |            0 |            0 | NULL       | NULL                | 177240302252540 | [ID, OUTSTANDING1, OUTSTANDING2, OUTSTANDINGP]
 4952 |         NULL |         NULL |         NULL | NULL       | 2022-12-15 13:30:02 | 177240302252701 | [ID, LASTACTION, LASTACTIONDATE]
 4952 |         NULL |         NULL |         NULL | ERA        | 2022-12-15 13:30:05 | 177240302255887 | [ID, LASTACTION, LASTACTIONDATE]
 4959 |       162.94 |            0 |            0 | NULL       | NULL                | 177240304204719 | [ID, OUTSTANDING1, OUTSTANDING2, OUTSTANDINGP]
 4959 |        160.0 |            0 |            0 | NULL       | NULL                | 177240304207643 | [ID, OUTSTANDING1, OUTSTANDING2, OUTSTANDINGP]
 4959 |       141.74 |            0 |            0 | NULL       | NULL                | 177240304209836 | [ID, OUTSTANDING1, OUTSTANDING2, OUTSTANDINGP]
 4959 |         NULL |            0 |            0 | NULL       | NULL                | 177240304212737 | [ID, OUTSTANDING1, OUTSTANDING2, OUTSTANDINGP]
 4959 |         NULL |         NULL |         NULL | CLOSE      | 2022-12-15 13:30:07 | 177240304212873 | [ID, LASTACTION, LASTACTIONDATE]
 4959 |         NULL |         NULL |         NULL | ERA        | 2022-12-15 13:30:07 | 177240304218096 | [ID, LASTACTION, LASTACTIONDATE]
 4959 |         NULL |         NULL |         NULL | NULL       | NULL                | 177240304219369 | [ID, LASTACTION, LASTACTIONDATE]
 4998 |         25.0 |            0 |            0 | NULL       | NULL                | 177330411767496 | [ID, OUTSTANDING1, OUTSTANDING2, OUTSTANDINGP]
 4998 |         NULL |         NULL |         NULL | CREATE     | 2022-12-15 16:41:06 | 177330411767632 | [ID, LASTACTION, LASTACTIONDATE]
 4998 |         55.0 |            0 |            0 | NULL       | NULL                | 177330411775790 | [ID, OUTSTANDING1, OUTSTANDING2, OUTSTANDINGP]
 4998 |         55.0 |            0 |            0 | NULL       | NULL                | 177330411781226 | [ID, OUTSTANDING1, OUTSTANDING2, OUTSTANDINGP]
```

The expected result should be the latest value of each column based on POS ordering and also the changed_cols to differentiate data NULLs vs spark NULLs.

The table is created via spark by reading from a JSON file. We are using the changed_cols field to differentiate NULLs that got generated by spark due to the field not being not present vs actual NULLs in the data itself.

If you look at the 4th record of ID:4959 we could see that the NULL in column OUTSTANDING1 is not because of field not being present but due to the data itself and that can be distinguished from changed_cols values.

**Expected output:**

```
  ID  | OUTSTANDING1 | OUTSTANDING2 | OUTSTANDINGP | LASTACTION |   LASTACTIONDATE    |                    changed_cols
------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 4952 |          0.0 |            0 |            0 | ERA        | 2022-12-15 13:30:05 | [ID, OUTSTANDING1, OUTSTANDING2, OUTSTANDINGP, LASTACTION, LASTACTIONDATE]
 4959 |         NULL |            0 |            0 | NULL       | NULL                | [ID, OUTSTANDING1, OUTSTANDING2, OUTSTANDINGP, LASTACTION, LASTACTIONDATE]
 4998 |         55.0 |            0 |            0 | NULL       | NULL                | [ID, OUTSTANDING1, OUTSTANDING2, OUTSTANDINGP]
```

I am able to rollup the changed_cols and get the distinct values but getting the latest value is not working.

```
trino:datalakepartncr_trino> select op_type,src.ID, lag(src.OUTSTANDING1) over (partition by src.ID order by pos),src.outstanding1, pos,array_distinct(flatten(array_agg(changed_cols) over (partition by src.ID order by pos))) from claim_event where src.ID in (4998,4952,4959) and op_type = 'U' order by op_ts, pos
```

Please provide some ideas on how to achieve this.

**Additional sample JSON data to easily load and test**

```
{"table":"TABLEA", "POS": 1, "ID": 244, "COLUMNA": 283.7, "changed_cols": ["ID", "COLUMNA"]}
{"table":"TABLEA", "POS": 2, "ID": 244, "COLUMNA": null, "changed_cols": ["ID", "COLUMNA"]}
{"table":"TABLEA", "POS": 3, "ID": 244, "COLUMNA": 200, "COLUMNC": "CLOSE", "changed_cols": ["ID", "COLUMNA", "COLUMNC"]}
{"table":"TABLEA", "POS": 4, "ID": 244, "COLUMNA": null, "COLUMNB": "user", "COLUMNC": "INTERIM", "COLUMND": 35000, "changed_cols": ["ID", "COLUMNA", "COLUMNB", "COLUMNC", "COLUMND"]}
{"table":"TABLEA", "POS": 5, "ID": 244, "COLUMNB": "user", "COLUMNC": "OPEN", "changed_cols": ["ID", "COLUMNB", "COLUMNC"]}
{"table":"TABLEA", "POS": 6, "ID": 244, "COLUMNB": "user", "COLUMNC": null, "changed_cols": ["ID", "COLUMNB", "COLUMNC"]}
{"table":"TABLEA", "POS": 1, "ID": 245, "COLUMNA": 283.7, "changed_cols": ["ID", "COLUMNA"]}
{"table":"TABLEA", "POS": 2, "ID": 245, "COLUMNB": null, "changed_cols": ["ID", "COLUMNB"]}
{"table":"TABLEA", "POS": 3, "ID": 245, "COLUMNA": 200, "COLUMNC": "CLOSE", "changed_cols": ["ID", "COLUMNA", "COLUMNC"]}
```

Expected Output of sample JSON:

If we take the latest changed value from the above events for the primary key(ID) it will look like

````
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------+
|ID |COLUMNA|COLUMNB|COLUMNC|COLUMND|COL_LIST                                |
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------+
|244|null   |user   |null   |35000  |[ID, COLUMNA, COLUMNC, COLUMNB, COLUMND]|
|245|200.0  |null   |CLOSE  |null   |[ID, COLUMNA, COLUMNB, COLUMNC]         |
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------+```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly - you have "correct" data only if column name is present in `changed_cols`. One approach is to use a bit monstrous approach via [`max_by`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#max_by) which will take in account only data which present in `changed_cols` array via [`if`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html?#if) function which will return `pos` if analyzed column is present in the array:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(ID, OUTSTANDING1, OUTSTANDING2, OUTSTANDINGP, LASTACTION, LASTACTIONDATE, pos, changed_cols) AS (
    values (4952,          0.0,            0, 0, NULL       ,NULL               , 177240302252540, array['ID', 'OUTSTANDING1', 'OUTSTANDING2', 'OUTSTANDINGP']),
         (4952,         NULL,         NULL, NULL, NULL       ,'2022-12-15 13:30:02', 177240302252701, array['ID', 'LASTACTION', 'LASTACTIONDATE']),
         (4952,         NULL,         NULL, NULL, 'ERA'      ,'2022-12-15 13:30:05', 177240302255887, array['ID', 'LASTACTION', 'LASTACTIONDATE']),
         (4959,       162.94,            0, 0, NULL       ,NULL               , 177240304204719, array['ID', 'OUTSTANDING1', 'OUTSTANDING2', 'OUTSTANDINGP']),
         (4959,        160.0,            0, 0, NULL       ,NULL               , 177240304207643, array['ID', 'OUTSTANDING1', 'OUTSTANDING2', 'OUTSTANDINGP']),
         (4959,       141.74,            0, 0, NULL       ,NULL               , 177240304209836, array['ID', 'OUTSTANDING1', 'OUTSTANDING2', 'OUTSTANDINGP']),
         (4959,         NULL,            0, 0, NULL       ,NULL               , 177240304212737, array['ID', 'OUTSTANDING1', 'OUTSTANDING2', 'OUTSTANDINGP']),
         (4959,         NULL,         NULL, NULL, 'CLOSE'    , '2022-12-15 13:30:07', 177240304212873, array['ID', 'LASTACTION', 'LASTACTIONDATE']),
         (4959,         NULL,         NULL, NULL, 'ERA'      , '2022-12-15 13:30:07', 177240304218096, array['ID', 'LASTACTION', 'LASTACTIONDATE']),
         (4959,         NULL,         NULL, NULL, NULL       ,NULL               , 177240304219369, array['ID', 'LASTACTION', 'LASTACTIONDATE']),
         (4998,         25.0,            0, 0, NULL       ,NULL               , 177330411767496, array['ID', 'OUTSTANDING1', 'OUTSTANDING2', 'OUTSTANDINGP']),
         (4998,         NULL,         NULL, NULL, 'CREATE'   , '2022-12-15 16:41:06', 177330411767632, array['ID', 'LASTACTION', 'LASTACTIONDATE']),
         (4998,         55.0,            0, 0, NULL       ,NULL               , 177330411775790, array['ID', 'OUTSTANDING1', 'OUTSTANDING2', 'OUTSTANDINGP']),
         (4998,         55.0,            0, 0, NULL       ,NULL               , 177330411781226, array['ID', 'OUTSTANDING1', 'OUTSTANDING2', 'OUTSTANDINGP'])
)

-- query
select ID,
       max_by(OUTSTANDING1, if(contains(changed_cols, 'OUTSTANDING1'), pos)) OUTSTANDING1,
       max_by(OUTSTANDING2, if(contains(changed_cols, 'OUTSTANDING2'), pos)) OUTSTANDING2,
       max_by(LASTACTION, if(contains(changed_cols, 'LASTACTION'), pos)) LASTACTION,
       -- handle arrays:
       array_distinct(flatten(array_agg(changed_cols))) changed_cols
    -- ... the rest of needed columns
from dataset
group by ID;
```

Output:

| ID | OUTSTANDING1 | OUTSTANDING2 | LASTACTION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4952 | 0.00 | 0 | ERA |
| 4998 | 55.00 | 0 | CREATE |
| 4959 | NULL | 0 | NULL |

Comment: If i just use row_number based ranking approch and filter the latest it wont work as the output will be 
```4952, NULL, NULL, NULL, ERA, 2022-12-15 13:30:05
4959, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
4998, 55.0, 0 , 0, NULL, NULL```
The main complexity here is to differentiate NULLs that originated due to missing fields vs actual NULLs that is part of data and giving precedence to it by using the changed_cols field values

Comment: @arunb2w ok. I will try to look into it later.

Comment: I have updated the title to add more clarity because thats what am expecting. To differentiate actual nulls that came in data vs JSON nulls

Comment: @arunb2w see the changed answer. I've used the original data cause it was easier to translate for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How to rollup the distinct changed cols of all the rows in the output? I tried something like this but it is not working
```select ID,
       max_by(OUTSTANDING1, if(contains(changed_cols, 'OUTSTANDING1'), pos)) OUTSTANDING1,
       max(array_distinct(flatten(array_agg(changed_cols) over (partition by ID order by pos))))
    -- ... the rest of needed columns
from dataset
group by ID;```

Comment: I wa able to do something lie this and it worked!
select ID, OUTSTANDING1, OUTSTANDING2,  array_distinct(flatten(changed_cols_agg))
from (
select ID,
       max_by(OUTSTANDING1, if(contains(changed_cols, 'OUTSTANDING1'), pos)) OUTSTANDING1,
       max_by(OUTSTANDING2, if(contains(changed_cols, 'OUTSTANDING2'), pos)) OUTSTANDING2,
       array_agg(changed_cols) changed_cols_agg
    -- ... the rest of needed columns
from dataset
group by ID
);

Comment: @arunb2w yes, also note that you don't need extra select you can do it "inline", i.e.  `array_distinct(flatten(array_agg(changed_cols))) changed_cols_agg` . Also you can try just using `set_union` if your version supports it.

Comment: @arunb2w and was glad to help! Updated answer to support arrays. P.S. if answer works for you - feel free to upvote and mark it as accepted one ;)

Comment: Sure. What version set_union supports? and which is more performant like array_agg and flatten or set_union?

Comment: @arunb2w I would guess that `set_union` should be at least as performant as composite approach, as for versions - currently it is supported only by Presto 0.239+ (not by Trino, created issue there) but the easiest way to check is just try substituting current approach with `set_union`.